# How can I reactivate the current tab in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

On resize method I want to call `tab('show')` method on the current tab. It causes the `show.bs.tab` be fired and I can do my stuff like moving an animated box over the selected tab in that event.

I tried this on resize

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  total.forEach(function(item, i) {
    let active_link = item.querySelector("li .nav-link.active")
    $(active_link).tab("show")
  });
}
```

However since the active tab is shown, it doesn't fire the event again. How can I force it to be reactivated?

Comment: This seems like an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). What actual problem are you trying to solve? My guess is that you should just be calling your event handler on resize, not on a side effect of resize.

Comment: @isherwood I explained more about my problem, but the main problem is just I can't fire an even on an activated tab.